# ZF2: Switching Layouts Based on Idenitity - which event to use

Tags: layout, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

To date I have had a single layout in my application, configured in module.config.php as follows:

```
  'view_manager' => array(
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        ),
```

I am now trying to switch the layout based on whether a user is logged in or not.  This information is available in my `Core\Auth` service, and I am using it in my `module.php` as follows:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
        ...

        $eventManager->attach('dispatch', function ($e) {
        $application = $e->getApplication();
        $auth = $application->getServiceManager()->get('Core\Auth');

        if (!$auth->isLoggedIn()) {
            $viewModel = $e->getViewModel();
            $viewModel->setTemplate('layout/public');
        }
    }, -1000000);
}
```

The problem is that I don't know which event to attach it to, and which priority to use.  If I attach it to:...

- ...the bootstrap or route event, it gets overridden
- ...the dispatch event with a high priority it gets overridden
- ...the dispatch event with a low priority, it overrides any layout changes that controller actions might make, e.g. $view->setTerminal(true)
- ...the render event, (again) it overrides changes made by actions

Where should I be attaching it?  And with what priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opps, my mistake.

I was doing the same `isLoggedIn()` test in my index/index action, which was muddying the results.  I have removed it and attached the layout switch to the route event, default priority, and so far it works fine!